# Trouble finding 11mm metal spacer rings

Tags: metal, acrylic-glass

## Introduction

Hello everyone, i am building a tank made out of Legos, it is a very ambitious project and it requires many components.

## Question

You may be wondering why i am asking here something related to a RC controlled tank.
The problem is related to the remote controller: I am building one myself and I'm following the instruction in this video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-BDCmwNssiw&list=WL&index=59&t=0s
My problem is that I can't find anywhere the metal 11mm spacer rings mentioned at 8:47

The ring has to be mounted onto an acrylic panel
I need a website because the local shops don't have what I'm looking for

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because, as per the guidelines, asking for "product and service recommendations ("Where can I get [product]?" or "Where can I find someone who does [service] in [area]?") is off-topic.

Comment: Hi Michele, this is basically a 'search for me' question. If an alternative approach to your problem is fine for you, you could rewrite your question and add a detailed description of the component that you need.

Comment: Down voted for asking us to watch a video link in order to get the info needed to answer the question. Links go bad, its better to describe or perhaps grab images of what the problem is, beyond trying to source a specific material item (which would be off topic.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because, as per the guidelines, asking for "product and service recommendations ("Where can I get [product]?" or "Where can I find someone who does [service] in [area]?") is off-topic

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a product recommendation and a different take on the question.

The spacers appear to have been constructed from commonly available hobby tubing. Many big-box hardware stores, small-box hardware stores and hobby shops will carry tubing suitable for your purpose.

You can also get away with plastic tubing of sufficient rigidity and wall thickness.

You would, of course, have to measure, mark and cut the tubing to the necessary length. I suspect that 11 millimeters is a ballpark figure and you could get away with being a millimeter or two off spec.

If you have the tools, drill a hole in a scrap of wood to match the outside diameter of the tubing you select, insert the tubing to your mark and cut the tubing with a saw held against the face of the scrap. For obvious reasons, the scrap has to have the hole drilled square to the face in advance.

Even without these tools and a scrap, you can cut the tubing a bit long and use a file or coarse sandpaper to square the ends and establish a final length.

One other option, which adds a bit to the cost, is to purchase a small tubing cutter to perform the cuts. It will create a square edge, cuts quite precisely on your mark and will also swage in the end of the tube slightly. In many uses, such a distortion on the tubing end is not desirable, but for your purposes, it's not going to be a problem.

[image: small tubing cutter]

The above tubing cutter is from an online listing from Advance Auto Parts, but most hardware stores will have similar products.

Comment: Good answer to a bad question... it should have been accepted, unless OP really does just want someone to tell them where to order the spacers.